# nested table not proper structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code and in this, I implemented a nested table but I want to display a table like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9goP.png). What changes did I forget?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td>First cell in first table. The cell to the right has the second table in it.</td>
<td>

    <table>
    <tr><td>nested table</td><td>nested table</td></tr>
   
    
    </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table> </div>
```

Comment: `<tr><td>nested table</td></tr>  <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>` change inner table to this. Show below for full answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! Add two `tr` in the nested table instead of two `td`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td>First cell in first table. The cell to the right has the second table in it.</td>
<td>
  <table>
  <!--Add two tr instead of two td in same tr-->
    <tr>
      <td>nested table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>nested table</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting two table row (`tr`). But you coded for two columns (`td`).......

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td>First cell in first table. The cell to the right has the second table in it.</td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>nested table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>nested table</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table> </div>
```